# Браузер не может найти функцию в обработчике ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, асинхронность

Бьюсь уже пятый час и никак не могу понять в чем проблема. Есть класс в котором реализован методы загрузки и обновления данных и методы запуска и остановки таймера. По таймеру вызывается функция загрузки данных(loadData) в которой через ajax загружаются данные, в колбеке вызывается функция обновления данных(updateData) и вот здесь возникает проблема: браузер почему-то не может найти эту функцию ошибка "main.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: this.updateData is not a function"

```
function Runnable()
{
    this.timerID;
    this.loadData = function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_handler.php",
            success: function(result) {
                try {
                    jsonObj = $.parseJSON(result);
                } catch (e) {
                    alert('Ошибка на сервере!');
                }
                //ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ ПРОБЛЕМА, ЭТА ФУНКЦИЯ НЕ НАЙДЕНА
                this.updateData(jsonObj);
            }
        });
    };

    this.updateData = function(events) {
        var countNewData = $(events).size();
        for (var i = 0; i < countNewData; i++) {
            $($('[id ^= "event_"]')[$('[id ^= "event_"]').size() - 1]).remove();
            $('#wrap').prepend('<div id="event_' + (countNewData - i) + '">' + events[i] + '</div>' );
        }
    };

    this.startTimer = function() {
        this.timerID = setInterval(this.loadData, 1000);
    };

    this.stopTimer = function() {
        clearInterval(this.timerID);
    };

}





$(document).ready( function() {
    var r = new Runnable();
    r.startTimer();
});
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что тут: "this.updateData(jsonObj);" у вас тот самый this, который вы ожидаете?

Comment: Я не очень хорошо знаю js, но мне кажется что тут все правильно.  Здесь должен вызываться метод updateData объекта r класса Runnable.

Comment: я написал вам ответ, если мой вариант будет работать, то советую почитать вам про this в javascript. Он разный в разном контексте, нужно об этом помнить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В яваскрипте значение *this* зависит от того как была объявлена функция, и от того как она вызывается. Подробнее можно [узнать в справке](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Конкретно в коде из вопроса `this` меняется дважды:

1. `this.timerID = setInterval(this.loadData, 1000);` - таким образом *this* внутри функции `loadData` которая будет вызываться по таймеру - уже не будет объектом ожидаемого класса.
2. `$.ajax({ success: function(result) {` - в данном случае `this` опять меняется на объект *ajax*.

Решений может быть несколько:

1. сохранять значение `this` перед вызовом и использовать внутри не *this*, а сохраненную переменную
2. использовать [*bind*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) при передаче
3. использовать [стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

   ```
   this.loadData = () => {
       $.ajax({
           success: (result) => {
               ...
               this.updateData(jsonObj);
           }
       });
   };
   ```

Comment: стрелочные же не все браузеры поддерживают) на бинд неправильная ссылка

Comment: @Jean-Claude, а я не сказал, что все поддерживают:) это всего лишь один из вариантов решения. На бинд поправил ссылку

Answer (score 0):

Вероятнее всего, что внутри `$.ajax({...` вы делаете обращение к вашей функции через *this*, но ваша функция объявлена в другом контексте, другими словами, внутри `$.ajax({...` другой *this*. Поправьте меня, если я не прав. Спасибо.
Попробуйте просто объявить

```
var updateData = function(events) {...
```

а внутри `$.ajax({...`

вызвать вашу функцию так: `updateData(jsonObj)`;

Comment: не, области видимости здесь ни при чем, здесь все в контекст вызова упирается